# Wpf animate GeometryDrawing position

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, ellipse

I've created a Usercontrol that has a SVG in it. I used the SvgToXaml converter to do this (awesome tool). The image is working correctly, but now i want to animate one of the `GeometryDrawing` in the 'DrawingGroup' However since this is new to me using a `DrawingImage` i cannot seem to find the right spot to put my storyboard and also figure out what story board i would use.

```
<Image x:Name="myImage">
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V221.89 H661.53 V0 H0 Z">
                    ---- GeometryDrawing #1 ----
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <EllipseGeometry
                                x:Name="MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry"
                                Center="191.85,167.5"
                                RadiusX="33.81"
                                RadiusY="33.81" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    ---- GeometryDrawing #3 ----
                    ---- GeometryDrawing #4 ----
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

What i want to achieve is that `MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry` upon Load the `EllipseGeometry` at x 0 and then moves to x 167 in 5 seconds or so.